How can I change "in cart" text of block button?
The default behavior of a Woocommerce AddToCart Button is to first show "Add to Cart". Once clicked, it will go to a Loading State and checks the AJAX request, then shows "in cart {number}".
I couldn't find any action/filter to hook into. I can change the "Add to Cart" text in many different ways: hooks, translations, CSS, etc. But for the latter state, JavaScript is in charge, and, as a result even translation doesn't work.
While I very much like this functionality, I have to find a way to replace "in cart" with an icon while keeping the {number} part.
Please let me know if you have robust and clean way of doing this.
Thank you in advance.
I tried reproducing the very structure of the HTML, even the wp-data attributes, but I couldn't get far, since after replacing this with the default woocommerce html, the interactivity is gone.
I'm not that good at Javascript, but as ugly as it seems, I even tried to change it with a script that looks for the addedtocart event, and changes the text. In vain...
The obvious way is to create a customized button from scratch but I won't be able to do it at this moment because I have other requirements to deliver.
I also tried whatever Chatgpt had to offer with its vast knowledge, to no success.

Please don't add solutions inside the answers. Consider posting an actual answer if you've figured out a way to solve your issue

Ah, I see. I tried to post an answer but it prompted me that I better choose between a comment / edit. :)) guess I trust the UX more than my gut :)) got it.

No, it's totally fine to self-answer a question on StackOverflow if you've figured it out yourself - Can I answer my own question? - Just make sure it's not GPT-created and you add enough explanation so your answer can help other people in the future

Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or a CSS problem? Please remove the irrelevant tags

It's a wordpress problem, hence the PHP (my solution). It's a problem with Woocommerce Blocks, and that heavily relies on JS (Irfan's answer). And I even tested several CSS solutions.
Now that it's solved, we can actually say it's a PHP problem, because it does have a PHP solution. I will remove CSS.

Please remove the unneccessary tags then

A rather clean solution I found:
add_filter( 'gettext', function( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    if ( 'woocommerce' === $domain && '%s in cart' === $text ) {
        $translated_text = ' %s';
    }
    return $translated_text;
}, 10, 3 );

I had tested translation, but I was expecting "%d in cart" which was wrong and I thought that's out of question. With "%s in cart" it works.
I removed the "in cart" text and added the icon using a ::before psuedo-element.

That is a perfect one, cool that it works, I also tested this new solution which I have posted is also working perfectly. But the code is a little complex as I have maintained the pipeline to easily execute in host system.
But happy to heat that you found the bug and fix it cheers

You can write custom javascript to do this
When the button text changes to "in cart {number}", dynamically replace the text "in cart" with your desired icon (e.g., using HTML or a FontAwesome icon).
you can write the javascript code in custom.js or function.php script file of your theme
Here is the simple .js code which you can paste in custom.js in your theme


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Listen for changes in WooCommerce block buttons
    const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutationsList) {
        for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
            if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                const target = mutation.target;
                // Check if the button text contains "in cart"
                if (target.innerText.includes('in cart')) {
                    const match = target.innerText.match(/(\d+)/); // Extract the number
                    if (match) {
                        const number = match[1];
                        // Replace button content with custom icon and number
                        target.innerHTML = `<span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: center;">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cart-check" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                              <path d="M10.97 4.97a.235.235 0 0 0-.304.304l1.28 3.211a.25.25 0 0 0 .233.176h2.54a.25.25 0 0 0 .234-.176l1.28-3.211a.235.235 0 0 0-.305-.304l-3.213 1.28a.235.235 0 0 0-.176.233v2.54a.235.235 0 0 0 .176.234l3.213 1.28a.235.235 0 0 0 .305-.305l-1.28-3.213a.25.25 0 0 0-.233-.176h-2.54a.25.25 0 0 0-.234.176l-1.28 3.213a.235.235 0 0 0 .305.305l3.213-1.28a.235.235 0 0 0 .176-.233v-2.54a.235.235 0 0 0-.176-.234l-3.213-1.28z"/>
                              <path d="M5.5 1a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.415 1H13a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.621l-1 4a.5.5 0 0 1-.485.379H5.415a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.415 1A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 7.5V2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 4.5 1zm0 1A.5.5 0 0 0 5 2.5v5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h7.565a.5.5 0 0 0 .485-.621l-1-4a.5.5 0 0 0-.485-.379H5z"/>
                            </svg>
                            &nbsp; ${number}
                        </span>`;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Target WooCommerce Add to Cart Buttons
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.wp-block-button__link'); // Adjust selector if needed
    buttons.forEach(button => {
        observer.observe(button, { childList: true, subtree: true });
    });
});



function custom_add_to_cart_button_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-add-to-cart', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_add_to_cart_button_script');



add_action('wp_footer', function () {
    ?>
    <script>
    /* Paste the JavaScript code here */
    </script>
    <?php
});

here how you add that .js function to your website

Dear Irfan, thanks for the reply.
I tried your script and added log statements, it didn't notice any changes until I changed the "childList" method to "characterData".
I also had to check for three other scenarios:

when a product was already in cart before the latest visit. which was solved by an initial check.
when text doesn't change due to an unsuccessful add (and woocommerce takes charge) I solved this, too.
Last but not least: when a product is removed from cart and the observer fires before woocommerce changes back the text! I tried a delay of 0.1 seconds, didn't work.


Can you try this modified version? Its working here in my system.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Function to replace "in cart {number}" with an icon + number
    function replaceInCartText(button) {
        const currentText = button.innerText;
        if (currentText.includes("in cart")) {
            const match = currentText.match(/(\d+)/); // Extract the number
            if (match) {
                const number = match[1];
                // Replace button content with custom icon and number
                button.innerHTML = `
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: center;">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cart-check" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                          <path d="M10.97 4.97a.235.235 0 0 0-.304.304l1.28 3.211a.25.25 0 0 0 .233.176h2.54a.25.25 0 0 0 .234-.176l1.28-3.211a.235.235 0 0 0-.305-.304l-3.213 1.28a.235.235 0 0 0-.176.233v2.54a.235.235 0 0 0 .176.234l3.213 1.28a.235.235 0 0 0 .305-.305l-1.28-3.213a.25.25 0 0 0-.233-.176h-2.54a.25.25 0 0 0-.234.176l-1.28 3.213a.235.235 0 0 0 .305.305l3.213-1.28a.235.235 0 0 0 .176-.233v-2.54a.235.235 0 0 0-.176-.234l-3.213-1.28z"/>
                          <path d="M5.5 1a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.415 1H13a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.621l-1 4a.5.5 0 0 1-.485.379H5.415a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.415 1A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 7.5V2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 4.5 1zm0 1A.5.5 0 0 0 5 2.5v5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h7.565a.5.5 0 0 0 .485-.621l-1-4a.5.5 0 0 0-.485-.379H5z"/>
                        </svg>
                        &nbsp; ${number}
                    </span>`;
            }
        }
    }

    // Function to observe text changes in Add to Cart buttons
    function observeButtons() {
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".wp-block-button__link, .add_to_cart_button");

        buttons.forEach((button) => {
            // Initial check for already "in cart" buttons
            replaceInCartText(button);

            // MutationObserver to watch for text changes
            const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList) => {
                for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
                    if (mutation.type === "characterData" || mutation.type === "childList") {
                        setTimeout(() => replaceInCartText(button), 100); // Delay ensures WooCommerce's DOM changes complete
                    }
                }
            });

            // Observe changes in the button
            observer.observe(button, {
                childList: true,
                subtree: true,
                characterData: true,
            });
        });
    }

    // Observe WooCommerce buttons on page load
    observeButtons();

    // Re-check buttons after AJAX events (WooCommerce uses AJAX for cart updates)
    document.body.addEventListener("updated_wc_div", observeButtons); // For cart updates
    document.body.addEventListener("added_to_cart", observeButtons); // For successful adds
});



place the following code lines in custom-add-to-cart.js
function enqueue_custom_cart_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-add-to-cart', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-add-to-cart.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_cart_script');


Thanks for a second try. Testing your solutions I learned about Observer. I tried it, It works the first time add to cart button is hit. But it still doesn't work for Ajax remove from cart. Also if you click the add to cart button more than one time, it accumulates the numbers...
unsuccessful will result in 1, 11, 111,11111 etc
and successful -> 1, 222, 3333 etc

Please explain how this would solve the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers.
